# How To Make A Rotating Playing Status On Discord.NET

Tags: c#, .net, bots, discord, discord.net

I want to make a playing status that changes every 10 Seconds or so, I know how to do that in JS, but not on C#. Is there a way to do this and if so, how do you do it?

I've been thinking maybe trying a `for` loop but i don't know how that would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can utilize `System.Threading.Timer` to achieve this.

```cs
//add this namespace
using System.Threading;
```

```cs
//create your Timer
private Timer _timer;

//create your list of statuses and an indexer to keep track
private readonly List<string> _statusList = new List<string>() { "first status", "second status", "another status", "last?" };
private int _statusIndex = 0;
```

You can use the ready event to kick things off. Simply subscribe the the Ready event on your DiscordSocketClient

```cs
private Task Ready()
{
    _timer = new Timer(async _ =>
    {//any code in here will run periodically       
        await _client.SetGameAsync(_statusList.ElementAtOrDefault(_statusIndex), type: ActivityType.Playing); //set activity to current index position
        _statusIndex = _statusIndex + 1 == _statusList.Count ? 0 : _statusIndex + 1; //increment index position, restart if end of list
    },
    null,
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), //time to wait before executing the timer for the first time (set first status)
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); //time to wait before executing the timer again (set new status - repeats indifinitely every 10 seconds)
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: You can only update the status 5 times per minute so this is gonna drop the status once every minute. The recommended delay is 15 seconds

Comment: Interesting, I tested this over a duration of three minutes and it successfully updated each time. It's definitely something that the OP should note and probably increase the cycle time, but it does appear to be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few ways you can accomplish this, first I would suggest looking into a simple Timer class. [.NET Timer Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netcore-2.2)

Based on the documentation above, you could make a simple console app

```
private static Timer timer;
private static List<string> status => new List<string>() { "Status1", "Status2", "Status3", "Status4" };
private static int currentStatus = 0;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CreateTimer();
    Console.ReadLine();
    timer.Stop();
    timer.Dispose();
}

private static void CreateTimer()
{
    timer = new Timer(10000);
    timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
    timer.AutoReset = true;
    timer.Enabled = true;
}

private static async void OnTimedEvent(Object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    DiscordSocketClient client = new DiscordSocketClient(new DiscordSocketConfig()
    {
         //Set config values, most likely API Key etc
    });

    await client.SetGameAsync("Game Name", status.ElementAtOrDefault(currentStatus), ActivityType.Playing);
    currentStatus = currentStatus < status.Count - 1 ? currentStatus +=1 : currentStatus = 0;
}
```

The OnTimedEvent function shows a quick example how you could do something using the discord.net library.

Comment: My application runs on .NET Framework. What you have given me is .NET Core Code. If this is also suppose to work in .NET Framework, well then I don't know why it ain't working in my case. Discord.NET is mostly an asynchronous API.

Comment: Sorry, in the top left you can change the it from .NET Core to Framework, you would only have to add the async modifier to account for the HTTP Request, updated the example to show async and API call.